# How to fix Highchart Sparkline tooltip not showing

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I want to use this highcharts demo code: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/sparkline

But the tooltips don't look right on the demo page. Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.highcharts-container {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

See if you can make it work without important, but that's the part that clips the tooltip, its direct parent.